# MERN app works locally but breaks on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I am trying to deploy [this MERN GitHub project](https://github.com/SirIsaacNeutron/writer) to Heroku. Heroku builds it fine and the site is live [here](https://writer-w.herokuapp.com/). However, the code on the Heroku site has a whole bunch of problems that don't occur when I run my site locally on my computer.

I think the problem might be the proxy server I set up (setupProxy.js):

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

I can't think of anything else that could be causing all the bugs on Heroku. I would really appreciate any assistance that can be given, since I've been dealing with this issue for some time now (I gave up on fixing it last year but have returned to it) and it's been very frustrating. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: @CodedMonkey 1) When you go to the site it says "Welcome, undefined" ("undefined" supposedly being a username). But this doesn't happen when run locally. 2) Trying to view the "Users" page fails even though it works locally. I remember encountering something about a proxy server which is why I included that information... 3) Creating posts doesn't work even though logging in and out does

Comment: @CodedMonkey err actually creating posts does "work" (I just created one using the Heroku website and I see it locally) but it's glitched on the heroku site (doesn't show the "delete" or "edit" buttons, and doesn't display post content correctly). I don't have any of these problems locally so I don't understand what the problem is in my code...